# How to connect to web socket using Node JS sdk and show it in front end

Tags: javascript, node.js

[This is the smartapi](https://github.com/angelbroking-github/smartapi-javascript) provided by my broker, written in Node.JS.

I used the example code provided to connect to web socket using api key and everything and write it in the console. But I want this data to be pushed to the front end.

I am new to Node.JS and front end for the same.

Below is the code that logs market data in console

```
var http = require("http");
var tickdata = {};
let { WebSocket } = require("smartapi-javascript");
let web_socket = new WebSocket({
  client_code: "XXXXX",
  feed_token: "XXXX",
  script: "nse_cm|2886&nse_cm|1594" //exchange|token for multi stocks use & seperator
});

web_socket.connect();
web_socket.on("tick", receiveTick);
function receiveTick(data) {
  console.log("Receive stock ticks::", data);
  tickdata = data;
}
//create a server object:
http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.write(JSON.stringify(tickdata)); //write a response to the client
    res.end(); //end the response
  })
  .listen(8080);
```

I want this data to be pushed to front end every second.

Comment: It looks like you are using web sockets. That is probably a good approach, assuming you are wanting to stream this data from the backend server to the frontend client. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: i dont know how to do that.. which is the easiest way.. AJAX.. React or can just to it using vannial javascript i am new to development.. please advise how to go abt it

Comment: also if you can give example code high level it will be great for me to learn